# Preventing the process from exiting when running a gulp task (so a server remains up)

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task that starts a server:

```
gulp.task('my-task', ['start-server'], function() {});
```

The gulp task `start-server` registers a listener:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
    server.stop();
});
```

But, I want the server to remain open. A bit like a `gulp-watch` task stays "open".

Currently, AFAICT, the Node.js process running the gulp task, exits upon completion of the gulp task and takes down the server with it.

How can I avoid the process exiting and taking the server down with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `gulp-nodemon` was meant to do:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon

Example implementation:

```
gulp.task('develop', function () {
  nodemon({ script: 'server.js'
          , ext: 'html js'
          , ignore: ['ignored.js']
          , tasks: ['lint'] })
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!')
    })
})
```

Comment: After reading the documentation, I am unclear how to integrate this. The following exhibits no change in behavior. `gulp.task('my-task', ['start-server'], function() {
 nodemon({});
}); ` It is not the monitoring of files I want. I want the gulp process to not exit until I manually kill it.